# Simple test post not working, node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am starting to learn React and Node.js. I created a very simple form and am attempting to submit it the traditional way (synchronously, no ajax) for learning purposes. Within the src directory I have a directory for the form, as well as another directory (model) for my node.js file to which I am submitting the form. When I click submit all I get is "cannot POST /model/controller.js". I have googled around and found nothing. Just trying to get the basics down. Thanks for you help.

The form in 'src/login/Login.js'

```
class Login extends React.Component {
render() {
    return (
        <form method="POST" action="/../model/controller.js" className="commonform" id="ajaxform" name="ajaxform">
        <h2>Please Sign In</h2>
        <Para class="usernotify" text= "test"/>
        <Input name="email" />
        <Input name="password" />
        <Button name="Sign In" id="ajaxSubmit"/>
        </form>
    );

}
}
```

The server page where I am submitting to 'src/model/controller.js'

```
var http = require('http'); 
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write('Hello');
    res.end();
  }).listen(8080);
```

Comment: I would suggest start with one. `Node` first, `React` second. I think you are confused of how to use both of them.

Comment: lots of things are missing here. react form is a bit different from the normal HTML form. you have to keep the state of each field and change and submit events, also binding event methods. i encourage you t read about react form.https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `'src/model/controller.js` is running an http server and it's listening on `/model/controller` for POSTS requests,  Do this for the form like from the docs https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

```
class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }


  handleSubmit(event) {
    // Post your data here using something like axios
    axios.post('http://localhost/model/controller', {
      ...your_data
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });


    //prevent form from being submitted automatically
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        ....
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi AppreciateCo in your controller you have added the server but missing the post method, please add something like this.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.post('/api/users', function(req, res) {
  var user_id = req.body.id;
  var token = req.body.token;

  res.send(user_id + ' ' + token);
});
```

You also need to change action in your html form, it should not be to a js file like controller.js, it should be to the controller end point which in my case is /api/users.

My suggestion is run your node js as separate module on port 8080, then change your action to do POST requests to http://localhost:8080/api/users